# Calculating rotation needed for elements of cube of cubes after shuffle to present facings outward

Tags: geometry

There is a cube made out of smaller cubes. Each small cube has an image on each outward looking facing (so they have either one, two or three images each). The image on a facing of smaller cube depends on part of which facing of larger cube this facing is a part of (e.g. the image). Cubes are separated into groups depending on amount of images and randomly shuffled (shuffle changes positions, but doesnt rotate them), and are put back on places cubes of their group used to have. The problem is that after shuffle I need all cubes to still present their facings with images outward, so there are no empty facing visible.

How do I calculate amount of rotation I need to apply to cubes, if I know their initial and final coordinates?

Thanks in advance!

[Example of the cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJSw.jpg)

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention one important detail - when shuffled cubes only take places of cubes with same amount of images on them

Comment: As worded, this problem is far too broad to be answerable. Is there a specific question you have about this? There are plenty of articles that discuss God's Number (the minimum number of rotations required to solve a Rubik's cube). Is that what you are looking for? [Math of the Rubik's Cube](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/mathematics-of-the-rubiks-cube-permutation-group/)

Comment: @i Not really. In my case smaller cubes are rotated individually, rather than in layers. Aslo I don't need to return cube to it's initial state, or compete any of the sides - I need to rotate cubes in ther new shuffled positions to face outward with their images, since shuffle doesn't rotate them, just moves them. The problem is that program that does this doesn't "know" where the images are, only it's old position and potition of cube it exchanged positon with. I could use some other programming tools to solve this, I was just wondering if there is a mathematical solution

Comment: Ok, so suppose you start with a cube that has only one outside face showing. Then it gets moved to a position with three outside faces showing. Where do the other two faces come from that it is going to show? Were they always there? Or can a cube with one outside face only move to a position where it can show one outside face?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, but yes, after shuffle a cube can only take place of a cube with the same amount of images on it

Comment: Then, there are eight smaller cubes that have three outside-facing faces. There are 12 smaller cubes that have only two outside-facing faces. There are six smaller cubes that have a single outside-facing face. This means there are $\dbinom{8}{2} = 28$ mappings between the cubes with three faces, $\dbinom{12}{2} = 66$ mappings between the cubes with two faces, and $\dbinom{6}{2} = 15$ mappings between the cubes with a single face. Because I do not have access to the code you are using for the shuffle or the rotations, it is not clear what sort of mathematical solution you seek.